# Websocket authentication with spring security

Tags: spring-security, websocket, tomcat7

I'm building a webapp with Spring MVC on Tomcat7 and I'm using Spring Security for user authentication. Apart from standard controllers, I also have a websocket servlet that needs connections to be authenticated.

The flow is as follows: a client connects to the server and is redirected to a login page, after successful authentication, the view he receives attempts to connect to the socket. I need to make sure, that only an authenticated user can start the websocket connection.

After some research, I found that authenticating the Http Upgrade request that starts the websocket connection should be enough. However I am stumped as to how to do that with the technologies I use. Simple interception of url's pointing to the websocket doesn't seem to work, as attempts to connect to the socket end with a 302 response, so I guess authentication fails and I am redirected to my login page. I would be grateful for some help in solving the problem.

Thanks

Comment: I think, and this is what I'm researching for my project as well, is that spring-security is checking for authentication inside form elements, but websocket authentication is sent as a header in the connect frame. I guess you need to write a filter to check for header elements for login/password details and validate the user.

Comment: The answer at this [question][1] might help your case.


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004081/springmvc-websockets-messaging-user-authentication-with-spring-security/27853391#27853391

Answer (score 0):

Spring security 4.x has native websocket support and it can integrate nicely with the authentication you made via HTTP.

You can check the documentation here:
http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.0.x/reference/html/websocket.html