# SpringMVC Websockets Messaging User Authentication with Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security, websocket

I have seen a couple of threads about this issue, but none of them seem to really answer the question directly.

Background, I have spring security installed, working, and running smoothly in other parts of the application.  My username is "developer".

Running on Java 7, Glassfish 4, Spring 4, and using Angular + StompJS

Let's get some code here:

```
package com.myapp.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.config.MessageBrokerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.EnableWebSocketMessageBroker;
import org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.StompEndpointRegistry;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketBrokerConfig extends AbstractWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    public final static String userDestinationPrefix = "/user/";

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/stomp").withSockJS().setSessionCookieNeeded(true);
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        //registry.enableStompBrokerRelay("/topic,/user");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic", "/user");
        registry.setUserDestinationPrefix(userDestinationPrefix);


    }


}
```

Ok, now here is a controller, to send out stuff every 3 seconds:

```
import org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate;

…

@Autowired
private SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;

…

@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 3000)
public void sendStuff () 
{

    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MimeTypeUtils.APPLICATION_JSON);
    System.out.print("Sending data! " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    //messagingTemplate.convertAndSend("/topic/notify", "Public: " + System.currentTimeMillis());

    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("developer", "/notify", "User: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
    messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser("notYou", "/notify", "Mr Developer Should Not See This: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
}
```

And finally the JavaScript using SockJS

```
    var client = new SockJS('/stomp');
    var stomp = Stomp.over(client);
    stomp.connect({}, function(s) {

        //This should work
        stomp.subscribe('/user/' + s.headers['user-name'] + '/notify', console.debug);

        //This SHOULD NOT
        stomp.subscribe('/user/notYou/notify', console.debug);

    });
    client.onclose = $scope.reconnect;
```

And finally, for kicks, the pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.websocket</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.websocket-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-messaging</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-websocket</artifactId>
        <version>4.0.6.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Here is what does work:

1. I can produce wonderfully communication back and forth between the client and the server
2. It's fast
3. `messagingTemplate.convertAndSend` and `messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser`

This is the problem (noted above): Anyone can subscribe to other users feeds.

Now, there are a few other versions of this floating around, I will list them below, and explain why the answers are all wrong:

[What are the security issues around an open websocket connection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16266775/what-are-the-security-issues-around-an-open-websocket-connection)

[Spring websocket with stomp security - every user can subscribe to any other users queue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23778451/spring-websocket-with-stomp-security-every-user-can-subscribe-to-any-other-use/24912974#comment38877147_24912974)

[Websocket: How To Push A Message To A Target User](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24282138/websocket-how-to-push-a-message-to-a-target-user/24912748#comment38877178_24912748)

Here's the problem:

- Look at `messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser` - All that does is add the "user prefix" and then the username provided and then use `messagingTemplate.convertAndSend` which does not apply security.
- Then people say that "you need to use spring security just like everywhere else" - the problem here is A) that I am SENDING data to the client asynchronously, so B) I will be using this code completely outside of the user's session, possibly from a different user (say to send a notification to another logged in user).

Let me know if this is too closely related to a different post, but I this is a big problem for me and I wanted to do this justice.

I can get more details though if anyone needs more details.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

New Spring Security 4x now fully support Web Socket, you can refer the link [Preview Spring Security WebSocket Support](http://spring.io/blog/2014/08/21/preview-spring-security-websocket-support)

Or [SpringSecuritySupportWebSocket.html](http://phuonghuynh.github.io/java/spring/2015/01/07/spring-security-support-websocket.html) in case you need a complete example,

Comment: Boy would that have been nice a few months ago!! :)

Comment: I still don't think this solves @Nitroware problem, which incidentally is mine too. The example given by phuong adds ROLE based permissions to the queue, but does not stop a user A in ROLE X from subscribing to message from another user B in ROLE X.
I think this problem still exists. What is needed is an authorization hook when a user subscribes to a message

Comment: @nsdiv You can use something like messages.simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/subscribe").access("@beanName.check(authentication,message)") This will use a Spring Bean with the name beanName and pass in the current Authentication and WebSocket Message. You implement the check method to return true or false. If you want more details, you will need to create a new question as the comment section is limitted

Comment: @RobWinch: Created a new question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34096412/spring-websockets-user-a-with-role-x-can-subscribe-to-user-b-with-role-xs-que

Comment: @phuong Second link is broken

Comment: @gstackoverflow fixed the broken link. Thanks ^

Answer (score 7):

I think you must make these changes:

1) You must not enableSimpleBroker for "/user" because it's a special queue handled automatically by the broker

2) if the server uses for example the annotation "@SendToUser("/queue/private")" the client must subscribe to the queue "/user/queue/private" : you must not prepend the username in the queue because it's a transparent operation handled by the broker

I'm sure this works correctly because I'm using it in my setup.

I've not tried with the convertAndSendToUser() method but since its semantic should be the same of the annotation, it should work too.

Comment: Great response, thanks so much! I will go ahead and try that now and update you/mark it as solves as soon as I know.

Comment: So I tried doing exactly what you had recommended and still it did not work.  The critical problem here between our two situations is this: You are using `@SendToUser` which already has the current users session and scope, and likely the user session.  I am trying to send notifications, possibly from another, to a different user using `convertAndSendToUser()` which is where i am getting my problems from

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.
I know it's late but you can use clientInboundChannel and clientOutboundChannel to stop subscriptions and messages that are not supposed to pass in/out.

Comment: You got this working using in-memory broker or remote JMS broker?

Comment: embedded spring broker

Answer (score 4):

You can override configureInbound method in a JavaConfig class extending AbstractSecurityWebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer.

```
@Override
protected void configureInbound(MessageSecurityMetadataSourceRegistry messages) {
    messages
            .nullDestMatcher().authenticated() 1
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/queue/errors").permitAll() 2
            .simpDestMatchers("/app/**").hasRole("USER") 3
            .simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/user/**", "/topic/friends/*").hasRole("USER") 4
            .simpTypeMatchers(MESSAGE, SUBSCRIBE).denyAll() 5
            .anyMessage().denyAll(); 6

    }
}
```

There, you can configure credentials to subscribe a channel, send messages or several other things, as mentioned in Spring WebSocket documntation https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/websocket.html#websocket-authorization

Comment: This is actually the correct answer. With this in place other user's receive an error if they try to subscribe to the broadcast destinations `/topic` or `/queue` or any destinations not explicility allowed.