# Spring WebSockets - User A with Role X can subscribe to User B with Role X's queue

Tags: spring-boot, spring-websocket

This is a follow up to [This comment about the same issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004081/springmvc-websockets-messaging-user-authentication-with-spring-security/27853391?noredirect=1#comment55907336_27853391)
I've tried messages.simpSubscribeDestMatchers("/subscribe").access("@beanName.check(authent‌​ication,message)") But it gives me an exception

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (8204) '‌'
>
> 15:10:51 [RMI TCP Connection(2)-127.0.0.1] AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext[WARN] - Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
>       org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'quoteService' defined in file [/Users/ndivadkar/projects/spring-websocket-portfolio/target/spring-websocket-portfolio/WEB-INF/classes/org/springframework/samples/portfolio/service/QuoteService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 0 of type [org.springframework.messaging.core.MessageSendingOperations]: : Error creating bean with name 'brokerMessagingTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'brokerMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerChannel' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'brokerChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in org.springframework.samples.portfolio.config.WebSocketSecurityConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in org.springframework.samples.portfolio.config.WebSocketSecurityConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (8204) '‌'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerMessagingTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'brokerMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerChannel' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'brokerChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in org.springframework.samples.portfolio.config.WebSocketSecurityConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in org.springframework.samples.portfolio.config.WebSocketSecurityConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (8204) '‌'
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:752)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1131)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1034)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:476)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
>           at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:762)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:757)
>           at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:480)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:663)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:535)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:489)
>           at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:136)
>           at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1231)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:1034)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4923)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5215)
>           at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
>           at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
>           at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1678)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>           at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:463)
>           at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:413)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300)
>           at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819)
>           at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1471)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1312)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1404)
>           at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:832)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
>           at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:323)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$256(TCPTransport.java:683)
>           at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>           at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>       Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerMessagingTemplate' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.simp.SimpMessagingTemplate]: Factory method 'brokerMessagingTemplate' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brokerChannel' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'brokerChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannel' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.messaging.support.AbstractSubscribableChannel]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannel' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' defined in class org.springframework.web.socket.config.annotation.DelegatingWebSocketMessageBrokerConfiguration: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor]: Factory method 'clientInboundChannelExecutor' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundChannelSecurity' defined in org.springframework.samples.portfolio.config.WebSocketSecurityConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.ChannelSecurityInterceptor]: Factory method 'inboundChannelSecurity' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' defined in org.springframework.samples.portfolio.config.WebSocketSecurityConfig: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.security.messaging.access.intercept.MessageSecurityMetadataSource]: Factory method 'inboundMessageSecurityMetadataSource' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot handle (8204) '‌'

I've created a sample project on [github](https://github.com/nsdiv/spring-websocket-portfolio/commits/security) (forked from https://github.com/rwinch/spring-websocket-portfolio/commits/security)

Comment: Please post full stacktrace

Comment: posted the stack trace and a sample project

Comment: This is not a complete stacktrace. Please include all caused bys